# Prove that for all a elements of F, -1*a=-a.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So far, I used the fact that $-1 = (-1+0)$ to get that $(-1+0)a = -1*a + a*0$. Since $a*0 = 0$, it follows that $-1*a + a*0 = -1*a + 0$. But now, I am back where I started...

Comment: Is $F$ a field?

Comment: Compute $-1*a + a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the following calculation:

$$0 = 0 \cdot a = (1 + (-1))\cdot a = 1\cdot a + (-1)\cdot a = a + (-1)\cdot a$$

Now since $a + (-1)\cdot a = 0$, we know $(-1)\cdot a$ is the additive inverse of the element $a$, which is denoted $-a$.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing $F$ is a field,

*Proof.*

We have that $a + (-1)(a) = a(1) + (-1)(a) = a(1 + (-1))$ by the multiplicative identity and distributive property, respectively.

By the additive inverse axiom, $a(1 + (-1)) = a(0) = 0$.

Thus $(-1)(a) = -a$, since the additive inverse of an element is unique. This completes the proof.

In this proof I made two claims: that for any $a \in F, a(0) = 0$, and that the additive inverse of an element $a \in F$ is unique. Now we should prove these.

To prove the first, we have that for any $a \in F$, $a(0) = a(0+0)$ by the additive identity, and then, by the distributive property, $a(0) = a(0+0) = a(0) + a(0)$. Adding $-(a(0))$ to both sides, we have $-(a(0)) + a(0) = -(a(0)) + a(0) + a(0)$. By the additive inverse axioms, the left side is $0$ and the right side is $a(0)$. Thus $0 = a(0)$.

Now to prove the second claim.

Let $a \in F$, and suppose $b_1 \in F$ and $b_2 \in F$ are its additive inverses. We shall show $b_1 = b_2$.

We have $b_1 = b_1 + 0 = b_1 + (a + b_2) = (b_1 + a) + b_2 = 0 + b_2 = b_2$, making use of the identity axioms, the fact that $b_2$ and $b_1$ are additive inverses of $a$, and the associativity of addition along the way.